# PyGame - Can't hide mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I've read everything I could find about the mouse in pygame and yet I miss something.

The device has (and will not) have a mouse attached so I need to remove the cursor from the game surface, ideally even before it draws the first screen.

But no matter what I try I always have a big oppalin cursor in the middle of the screen.

My current function is this :

```
  # initialize the pygame module
  pygame.init()
    
  # create a surface on screen that has the size of 240 x 180
  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((160,80))

  # define a variable to control the main loop
  running = True
  
  pygame.display.flip()

  # main loop
  while running:

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # hide cursor
    pygame.mouse.set_pos((160,80)) # my screen is actually 160 x 80 px so this should hide it by pushing it over the edge
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) # this should hide the mouse plain and simple

    # Here I do other unrelated (but working) stuff, like displaying images and text

    # event handling, gets all event from the event queue
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      # only do something if the event is of type QUIT
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        # change the value to False, to exit the main loop
        running = False
    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

And the mouse is still on screen, sometimes after a while it disappears.

I tried other method like making the cursor transparent, but that crash the app.

Note that I'm running Pygame on an Alpine Linux with direct output to the framebuffer on a Raspberry Pi. There's no mouse attached to the device but if I connect one I can move the cursor around.

Pygame is Version 2.1.2 (compiled and installed by pip)
Python is 3.10.0

Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

(sorry if it's a dumb question; I'm a total noob with python/pygame)

Comment: since you have a special device and os. did you try the same code hide or not hide mouse on normal environment, such as windows? that is to find whether the problem is platform specific.

Comment: good point! will try

Answer (score 1):

Just write the set_visible(False) outside the main loop, you don't need to call this every frame:

```py
  pygame.init()

  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((160,80))

  pygame.mouse.set_visible(False) # Hide cursor here

  running = True
 
  pygame.display.flip()

  # main loop
  while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
 
    # unrelated with your question but I also suggest that you clear your background inside the loop, at the contrary you likely will need this at each frame
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # ... your code, blitting images etc
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: I tried but still have the same behaviour (cursor in the middle of the screen) :(

Thanks for the other suggestion, I've updated the code.

Comment: That's weird.. have you removed the `pygame.mouse.set_pos((160,80))` ?

Comment: i did yes ;
no effect

Comment: Well I don't know then.. that code works well with me..